# Base64 returning empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64

I'm trying to upload images to the backend using base64, my upload is fine, but the backend receives an empty string. When I use  console log, I get the data. I don't know what went wrong here.

```
export default function NewPost() {

    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [file, setFile] = useState("");
    const [baseImage, setBaseImage] = useState("");

    const [newPost, setNewPost] = useState({
        userId: '',
        title: '',
        content: '',
        photo: '',
    });

      const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const res = await axios.post("/posts/", newPost);
            window.location.replace("/post/" + res.data._id);
            console.log('Saved Successfully');
            
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
    }

    const uploadImage = async (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const base64 = await convertBase64(file);
        setBaseImage(base64);
        console.log(base64);
        setNewPost({ ...newPost, photo: baseImage });
      };

      const convertBase64 = (file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
          fileReader.onload = () => {
            resolve(fileReader.result);
          };
          fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
            reject(error);
          };
        });
      };

  return (
    <div className="newPostPageContainer">
    <form className="newPostForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="newPostTitleImageUploadCont">
          <div className="newPostTitleContainer">
            <label className="newPostFormLabel">Post Title:</label>
            <input dir="auto" type="text"  
            onChange={e => setNewPost({ ...newPost, title: e.target.value })} />
            </div>
            <div className="newPostUploadImgContainer">
                <img src={baseImage} alt="" className="newPostUploadImg" />
                <label for="file">
                    <PublishIcon />
                </label>

              <input 
              type="file"
              id="file"
              onChange={(e) => { uploadImage(e); }}
              style={{display: "none"}} />

            </div>
            </div>
        
            <button className="newPostCreateButton" type="submit">
              <p className="newPostCreateButtonText">Create</p>
            </button>
    </form>
</div>

  );
}
```

Before that I used `<FileBase64 />` and it was working perfectly. But since it can't be customized I changed to this, trying to do my own function, some help here would be appreciated.

Comment: `setBaseImage` does not update the `baseImage` immediatelly. It will be updated on next render only. You are console logging `base64` variable and then setting `photo` to `baseImage` variable, which holds the closure-captured value which is not updated at that moment.

Comment: try `setNewPost({ ...newPost, photo: base64 });` for the reason above